# Change SSH username when connecting with Bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I just inherited a laptop with a project hosted on Atlassian, etc. I have setup Git, and my Bitbucket profile. Yet, when I perform

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket
```

the connection is made using the previous guy's user name. I have

- changed user name and email on both local **and** global Git configs
- have validated that the key files (i.e. `id_rsa` etc.) do not reference this user name
- performed a thorough file search for this specific user name

I do not know why SSH connects to Bitbucket with this user. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what does this command reveals? `ssh -vvv -T git@bitbucket` also do you have some specific setup in `~/.ssh/config` ?

Comment: Search your filesystem for where that string is: `find / | grep otherdude`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitbucket handles public keys globally, meaning that no two users may register the same SSH key. Therefore, when I tried to connect, Bitbucket assumed the previous user since the key that it found was still attached to the user account of my predecessor.

Generating a new SSH key, overriding the previous one, then adding the public key to my Bitbucket account solved it.

Now, `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` resolves with my user name.

### Edit

I also use a configuration file to manage my hosts

```
Host project1.bitbucket
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile path/to/pub_key_a

Host project2.bitbucket
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile path/to/pub_key_b
```

Then setup Git remote as

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@project1.bitbucket:orgname/project1.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

(Change `project1` with the repository name, and `orgname` with the owner's name of the repository, etc.)

This is how to use different SSH keys with different Git repositories, etc.